# I am trying to make two divs to be next to each other in a responsive way

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to make part of my responsive page look like: http://s17.postimg.org/k4bh7qxnj/Screen_Shot_2014_07_26_at_8_08_02_PM.png 
I have tried a few things and I got the result found at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TachionFiddle/4HkTS/3/

This is my code:

```
<div id="my-wrapper" style="
    max-width: 941px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;">
<div class="left-stuff" style="
display:inline-block;
width: 18%;">
    <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png" style="width: auto;     
        height: auto; max-width:50%;">
    <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png" style="width: auto; 
         height: auto; max-width: 50%;">
    <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png" style="width: auto; 
         height: auto; max-width: 50%;">
</div>
    <div class="right-stuff" style="display:inline-block;max-width: 75%">
    <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/gns7jkwkf/webbanner2.png" style="width: auto; height: auto; 
    max-width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the three side images to be closer to the web banner. I would like it to look like: http://s17.postimg.org/k4bh7qxnj/Screen_Shot_2014_07_26_at_8_08_02_PM.png

Comment: The jsfiddle link above shows a live version of what I have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the general idea:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-10">       
        <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png">
        <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png">
        <img alt="" src="http://s16.postimg.org/db3hs4ndt/sac_history.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-90">
        <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/gns7jkwkf/webbanner2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-10 img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-90 {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
.col-90 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4SScy/1/)

I would suggest putting the three blocks into one image and making the heights line up in photoshop, will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: yeah, it would, but I need to make it so that each of the three blocks can be separate links.

Comment: In that case, some careful photoshop planning could save you aches and pain down the road, good luck!